# Reading a file without echoing in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to read a file, but it keeps printing all of the data to the page without my asking it to do so.

The code is:

```
<?php

$htmlAppointmentPage = readfile('AppointmentPageTemplate.html');

?>
```

That's all of the code. For some reason it's echoing the contents of `AppointmentPageTemplate.html`.

Comment: You can read file with 2 functions. `file_get_contents` or use `curl`.

Comment: Sorry, but please [read the friendly manual](http://www.php.net/readfile). It explains the behavior and links to alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and not `readfile()`.

From the Manual:

> This function is similar to `file()`, except that file_get_contents()
> returns the file in a string, starting at the specified offset up to
> maxlen bytes. On failure, `file_get_contents()` will return FALSE.
>
> `file_get_contents()` is the preferred way to read the contents of a
> file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported
> by your OS to enhance performance.

Please note that if your file is very large, it would take a lot of memory (= the file's size) to place it into a variable. Make sure you don't go over the limit set in php.ini.

Answer (score 4):

`readfile` reads the contents of a file and outputs them to the page.

To get the contents of a file as string (and assign them to a variable), use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? How can it be improved?